# What does it mean when the Box-Cox pre-calculated lambda is negative?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation

I used guerrero to calculate a lambda from a sample of aus_retail dataset but it sometimes has given me a negative value. From what I understand, the lambda should be between 0 and 1.

I am not sure yet what it means with the negative value though I can put it in Box-Cox transformation (still valid, no error).

Someone mentioned in [SciPy's stats boxcox transformation unexpected behavior: negative exponent (lambda)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196631/scipys-stats-boxcox-transformation-unexpected-behavior-negative-exponent-lamb) that a negative lambda used in reciprocal transformation but I don't think it makes sense to perform reciprocal transformation here.

Any ideas why I got a negative lambda and should I rather use a log transformation to reduce variability in such situation?

```
> myseries <- aus_retail %>%
+   filter(`Series ID` == sample(aus_retail$`Series ID`,1))
> myseries_lambda <- myseries %>% features(Turnover, features = guerrero) %>% pull(lambda_guerrero)
> myseries_lambda
[1] -4.477264e-05
```

Comment: your lambda value is nearly 0. , Why are you transforming the observed series ...all the assumptions are about the error series from a model. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-to-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers and more broadly .... Logs can be useful but the suggestion for a power transform for an atheoretic model should never be made based upon the original data but on the residuals from a model which is where all the assumptions are placed that need to be tested.

Comment: "I don't think it makes sense to perform reciprocal transformation here" Why not?

Comment: This value of $\lambda$ is indistinguishable from the logarithm.

Comment: @NickCox it doesn't make sense if I want to interpret it. I mean if I don't care about interpretation or if I just follow what other people say about applying Cox-Box, then it may be valid? I think I just don't want to be a careless beginner who applies Box-Cox everywhere.

Comment: @whuber can you elaborate more on that? Do you mean the  λ here is very close to zero. Therefore, it is ok to use logarithm?

Comment: Reciprocals can make sense: the reciprocal of a time is in essence a speed. The reciprocal of sales doesn't have a simple substantive meaning that I can identify, but the literature on generalized linear models points the way to using a link function and getting predictions on the original scale. If you are willing to think of log sales, why not reciprocal? All that said, -4.477264e-05 is essentially zero and not at all close to -1.

Comment: Here's what you can do: plot the logarithm over a wide range (two orders of magnitude would be more than enough) and overplot the Box-Cox transformation with your $\lambda.$ See how they differ.  Here's the `R` code: `lambda <- -4.477264e-05;
curve(log(x), 0.1, 10);
curve((x^lambda-1)/lambda, add=TRUE, col="Red")` Or, more simply, plot their ratio: `lambda <- -4.477264e-05; curve((x^lambda-1)/lambda/log(x), 0.1, 10)`

Comment: They are almost identical thanks @whuber